# ssh, hashed known_hosts: extract plain text and use wildcards

Tags: ssh, openssh

In `ssh` clients, file `.ssh/knwon_hosts` may use plain text (this happens, for example, in FreeBSD 12.0):

```
<ip_address> ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEIlD8R6Kxj9CdToar+3ay4B0yE65dP0EYoRJjEEgLjmvCTIv59DBp+0j2z0+NM0hxxJew79i1bYuN02lEvT2/E=
```

or it may be hashed (as in Ubuntu 18.04):

```
|1|3Et6QShrP2OrD4tWdOGP3jy3YC4=|f2FrJ5tOjjmFSrGWyen1DokJyLc= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBIyZLGNvIADWL5SSkohBmDCVpLUzAHNejqQAXP3SSY300YIdNKCn3jqGmFAJiKB1CY0HnVirgFjdAKpyw3+6yzo=
```

**Question 1**

Is it possible to obtain the plain text lines from an hashed `known_hosts`?

---

Ubuntu [sshd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man8/sshd.8.html#ssh_known_hosts%20file%20format) states that:

> Only one hashed hostname may appear on a single line and none of the above negation or wildcard operators may be applied.

I am not sure about what it's meant here.

**Question 2**

Does that mean that addresses like `192.168.*.*` can never be accepted in the hashed form of `known_hosts`, even when they are created as plain text and then manually hashed?

---

As in a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521269/ssh-accept-two-key-fingerprints-for-the-same-server-ip), I am using these clients: `OpenSSH_7.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a-freebsd  20 Nov 2018` and `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`.

Comment: Per Ulrich's answer, this is the reason they are known as "one way hash" functions.

Comment: The difference is whether `HashKnownHosts` is set to `yes` or `no` in the configuration, not which distribution or unix-like OS you are using (although different distributions may set different values in the _default_ ssh_config).

Answer (score 5):

No and yes, in that order. The purpose of hashing the line is to obscure the hosts that you have previously connected to, so it's the very purpose of the hash function to make it (for practical purposes) impossible to tell what hostname belongs to it.

By extension, you cannot really make wildcards work with hashed hostnames: if I want to connect to `webhost47`, and the lines are hashed, how do I even find out there's a line that matches `webhost*`? A hash is a trap door, I can only find that line by hashing `webhost*` and checking. But I'd also have to check for `?ebhost47`, `w?bhost47`, `??bhost47`, etc. etc., so that's not really reasonable.

(I guess the comment also means that you can't have

```
hashblurb1,hashblurb2 ssh-rsa …
```

with hashed hostnames, even though you can have

```
hostname1,hostname2 ssh-rsa …
```

and I don't see a technical reason righ tnow why you couldn't have that.)

Comment: You are meaning: `ssh` doesn't know where and how I can have used a wildcard character while creating `known_hosts`. So, `webhost*`, `?ebhost47` and so on are all possible positions/usage of wildcards, which should be all checked, and it is unpractical. Did I understand correctly? And yes, `hostname1,hostname2 ssh-rsa …` is feasible (as suggested in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521293/48707) answer), but only when `known_hosts` is plain text, not hashed.